# Why is IE not storing my Cookie?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I'm developing a (J2EE) website, and the cookies it sends are being persisted on Chrome and Firefox, but not IE.  I've even set IE up to 'allow all cookies', but the ones from my site are not being persisted.  Google, Twitter etc, cookies *do* get persisted.

Using Fiddler for IE, I see that my login page is correctly sending a cookie:

```
Response sent 65 bytes of Cookie data:
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1C5C8622CEC9338714F72A3CBFB5DDF8; Path=/tms/; HttpOnly

Response sent 132 bytes of Cookie data:
Set-Cookie: tms-remember-me=superuser; Version=1; Domain=""; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Sat, 03-Jun-2017 01:40:21 GMT; Path="; HttpOnly;"; Secure
```

**EDIT**
I've added a P3P header; Fiddler now says

```
P3P Header is present:
CP="CURa ADMa DEVa CONo HISa OUR IND DSP ALL COR"
```

But IE still won't persist the cookie.  Any idea why?

Comment: That's what it says: "Is the reason IE is not persisting this cookie likely to be the absence of a P3P header?". What is your question?

Comment: Is IE storing cookies for other websites, such as Amazon?

Comment: @Dave yes.  twitter, google, etc

Comment: Then the issue is your code? What does not persist mean? Does it expire quickly or not set?